# $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ such that $P(X_i=1)=P(X_i=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$. Denote $S=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. Prove $P(X>\frac{n}{10})<2^{-cn}$

Tags: probability

$X_1,\cdots,X_n$ are iid random variables such that $P(X_i=1)=P(X_i=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Denote $X=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.

Prove $P(X>\frac{n}{10})<2^{-cn}$ for some $c>0$

I try to use the central limit theorem but I get stuck.

$E[X_i]=0, \sigma=1$

$$P(X>\frac{n}{10})=1-P(X\leq\frac{n}{10})=1-P(\frac{X-\mu n}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}\leq\frac{n-\mu n}{10\sigma\sqrt{n}})=1-P(\frac{X-\mu n}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}\leq\frac{n-\mu n}{10\sigma\sqrt{n}})=1-P(Z\leq\frac{n}{10\sqrt{n}})=1-P(Z\leq\frac{\sqrt{n}}{10})$$

Please help

Thanks !

Comment: What is $X$ (without indices) in this question?

Comment: Notice that $\frac{X + 1}{2}$ is Bernoulli of parameter $\frac{1}{2}$ and the sum of Bernoulli's distribution is binomial.

Comment: It says $c \gt 0$. What if $c \to \infty$?

Comment: @MathLover c is a constant

Comment: @JoseAvilez fixed

Comment: He says for some $c$. It means $c$ is constant. we can't say $c \to \infty$.

Comment: yes but the question does not state an upper limit on $c$. If $c$ is very large, RHS would be near zero.

Comment: You can arrive at this result by using [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality).

Comment: Instead it should probably say for some $c$...

Comment: Fixed , there is a way to solve it without  Hoeffding's inequality ?

Comment: Are you assuming independence?

Comment: @ECL Yes , I added this detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special case of Bernstein's inequality or Chernoff's bound. But I am not going to use that inequality here.

Consider $e^{tX}=\prod_{i=1}^n e^{tX_i}$. The expectation of which is $\mathbb E(\prod_{i=1}^n e^{tX_i})=(\frac{e^{t}+e^{-t}}{2})^n$ So, by Markov's inequality, the probability of $X\ge n/10$ (or $e^{tX}\ge e^{nt/10}$) is at most  $(\frac{e^{t}+e^{-t}}{2})^n/e^{nt/10}$, or, it is $(\frac{e^{t}+e^{-t}}{2e^{t/10}})^n$.

Take $t=0.1$, we know that $\frac{e^{0.1}+e^{-0.1}}{2e^{0.01}}<0.996$. Thus, $X\ge n/10$ with probability $\le 0.996^n$. Take $c=-\log_2 0.996$ suffice.

Comment: (+1) .. but isn't this essentially this the Chernoff Bound ?

Comment: @Thomas Yes this is kind-of essentially the proof of Chernoff's bound... I assume the person asked this question is not allowed to use or don't know about the Chernoff's bound, so I had written in this way. The first sentence said that "This is a special case of Bernstein's inequality or Chernoff's bound" actually...

Comment: I doubt that if you do not know the chernoff bound one can arrive at that solution in a reasonable  time...

Comment: @Thomas if one learned about the moments (moment-generating functions), one may be able to derive this thing actually... I think this is a general technique rather than specifically used to derive the Chernoff's bound or other concentration bounds...

Comment: Probably yes, if you are smart enough you can find the technique on your own... ( I would not :D )... if you know it, than the problem is quite straightforward...

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach (It's not an answer to the problem but may be it can help) :
$$\dfrac{X_i + 1}{2}$$
is a Bernoulli distribution of parameter $\dfrac{1}{2}$ then :
$$Y = \sum_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{X_i + 1}{2} = \dfrac{X + n}{2}$$
is a binomial distribution of parameter $\left(n, \dfrac{1}{2}\right)$.
We deduce that :
$$p\left(X > \dfrac{n}{10}\right) = p\left(\dfrac{X + n}{2} > \dfrac{11n}{20}\right) = p \left(Y > \dfrac{11n}{20}\right)$$

1. By a direct calculi :
   $$p\left(X > \dfrac{n}{10}\right) = \dfrac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k = q}^n \binom{n}{k}$$
   with $q = \left\lfloor \dfrac{11n}{20} \right\rfloor + 1$.
2. By bienayme-chebyshev inequality :
   $$p\left(X > \dfrac{n}{10}\right) = p \left(Y - \dfrac{n}{2} > \dfrac{n}{20}\right) \leq p \left(\left|Y - \dfrac{n}{2}\right| > \dfrac{n}{20}\right) \leq \dfrac{100}{n}$$